# How to update mysql column with ArrayList value in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

I am working on a java gui based application, you can see the application's detailed view in the following image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8byAX.jpg

when I check one of the checkboxes that are columns from the database. then the value of the column I put into ArrayList and then I encrypt it using rc4.

I put the encryption results back into ArrayList. then the encryption results in ArrayList I want to enter back into the database column that is checked, in this case updating the contents of the checkboxes with the results of encryption in ArrayList.

So how do you make it work?

I have tried using query update but no luck.

this is the code that I'm working on:

```
         try{
          Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"","root","");
          Statement stmt=con.createStatement();


         for(int i =0; i < box.size();i++){
             if(box.get(i).isSelected()){
                 //System.out.print(box.get(i).getText().trim());
                 ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select "+box.get(i).getText().trim()+" from "+jComboBox3.getSelectedItem()+";");
                 while(rs.next()){
                    isikolom = rs.getString(1);
                    isi.add(isikolom);

                    String getkey = jTextField1.getText().toString();
                    byte[] key = getkey.getBytes();
                    RC4 rc = new RC4(new String(key));

                    String plainText = isikolom;
                    byte[] enText = rc.encrypt(plainText.getBytes());
                    String encrypted = new String(enText, "UTF-8");
                    isiencrypsi.add(encrypted);

                    byte[] deText = rc.decrypt(enText);
                    String descrypted = new String (deText,"UTF-8");
                    isideskripsi.add(descrypted);
                 }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
            sb.append("UPDATE ").append(jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString()).append("SET ");
            for (int x = 0; x < isiencrypsi.size(); x++){
                sb.append(box.get(i).getText().toString()+" = ").append(isiencrypsi.get(x).toString()).append(" where 1"); 

                String query = sb.toString();
                PreparedStatement presatet = con.prepareStatement(query);
                presatet.executeUpdate();
        } 
        }
     }

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        System.out.print(e);
    }
```

and when I run the code I get an error:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= b where 1' at line 1

how to make this work? and where is the fault?

Comment: Try removing the `.append(" where 1")`, I fail to see how it could serve any purpose. The best practice would be to stop crafting SQL statements from strings and properly use prepared statements instead.

Comment: And if it doesn't work, you need to check the content of the `query` Strings you create in your last for loop, there must be some conditions which lead to incorrect statements. You'll preferably want to use a step-by-step debugger, but if you can't logging the string or printing it to stdout could already help

Comment: As Aaron suggested it is best practice to use Preparestatements instead of building a query string. To quickly figure out what is happening with the syntax though, just print out the `String query = sb.toString();` and either edit your question with that printout, or you can look at it to see where the syntax error is.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, the update was successful, but now the problem is that all column contents are affected by the update, for example data in the column before the update [admin, employ, proctor], and I have the following arraylist [asas1, asas2, asas3] , after updating the contents of the column will be like this [asas3, asas3, asas3], how do I update the contents of the column so that it matches the arraylist, is it possible to update using the index as where clause? if yes, how is the syntax?

Comment: thank you for your help, the problem has been resolved. I use the replace statement